# If $X$ is a union of contractible cell complexes whose intersection is also contractible, then $X$ is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a cell complex that is a union of two contractible subcomplex whose intersection is contractible. Then $X$ is contractible.

I found some solution: Let $X = U\cup V$ with $W = U\cap V$, where $U,V,W$ are all contractible subcomplexes. First consider the quotient map $q:X\to X/W=:X_1$ is a homotopy equivalence because $W\simeq \{\text{pt}\}$. Since $q$ is cellular, $q(U)$ is  a subcomplex and $q(U)\simeq U/W\simeq U\simeq\{\text{pt}\}$. The quotient $q_1:X_1\to X_1/q(U)$ is again a homotopy equivalence. Observe that the restriction of $X\to X_1\to X_1/q(U)$ to $V$ is surjective and $X_1/q(U)\simeq V/W\simeq V\simeq\{\text{pt}\}$. Combining all the homotopy equivalences, we conclude that $X$ is contractible.

1. I read the definition of 'cellular map' in some website and I understood the quotient map is a cellular map. But I don't understand why this implies $q(U)$ is a subcomplex of $X/W$.
2. Also in the proof they said $q(U)\simeq U/W$. Why is that? Is this true for general setting? i.e. if $f:X\to X/A$ is a quotient map where $X$ is a topological space and $A\subset X$ is a subspace, and we let $B\subset X$ be a subspace. Then $f(B)\cong B/A$ (homeomorphic)?
3. Why is $X_1/q(U)\simeq V/W$?

The above proof can be seen [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/569bbdebdc5cb42985820ac4/t/5d8159142eff252b93ea8266/1568758037169/241-hw1-solutions.pdf).

Edit: Proof of 2)
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} B @>f>> f(B)\\ @VqVV @VidVV\\ B/A @>\tilde{f}>> f(B) \end{CD}$$

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} B @>q>> B/A\\ @VfVV @VidVV\\ f(B) @>\tilde{q}>> B/A \end{CD}$$
Easy to check that $\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{q} = id$ and $\tilde{q}\circ\tilde{f}=id$.

Comment: The answer to 2 is yes.

Comment: You're right to have concern. For $1)$ it's not sufficient that $q$ be cellular. What is important is the way in which $X/W$ is given its cellular structure. If you think about how this is done it will go a long way to answering your question $2)$.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you for your comment. Yeah, I know that $X/W$ has its natural cell structure. I think what you're saying is that once I know 2), then 1) follows right? I tried to prove 2) in a general setting and I first thought of using a universal property of quotient space but can't see the specific way. could you help?

Comment: @NoelLundström Could you explain why?

Comment: I just edit the post to show my proof of question 2. I wonder if it's right

Comment: Yes that looks right, the tricky part is proving continuity of $ \tilde f$ and $\tilde q$.

Comment: @NoelLundström I thought it follows from the universal property