# Restriction of homotopy equivalence which is surjective is homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I have a question related to my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4038343/668308). The question is

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a homotopy equivalence and $A\subset X$ be a subspace such that $f|_A:A\to Y$ is surjective. Then $f|_A$ is a homotopy equivalence between $A$ and $Y$?

The original problem I concerned in my previous post is: restriction of $X\to X_1\to X_1/q(U)$ to $V$ is surjective so $X_1/q(U)\simeq V/W$ (3) in my post). Could you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following counterexample : let $X$ be a contractible space; then $X\to *$ is by definition a homotopy equivalence.

Take a subspace $Y$; as long as $Y\neq X$, the restriction to $X\setminus Y$ will be surjective.

However it is rarely the case that all $X\setminus Y$ are also contractible.

Consider, e.g. $X= \mathbb R, Y=\{0\}$, $X= \mathbb R^2, Y= \{(0,0)\}$. In fact, continuing this way with $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ shows that you could have a space that is still $n$-connected, but not contractible anymore.

Here's also a slightly less trivial example : consider the projection $S^1\times [0,1]\to S^1$. This is a homotopy equivalence, however if you remove an interior point on the left hand side you will get something very different, which is in fact homotopy equivalent to a wedge of two circles $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I still don't understand the original question i.e. $X_1/q(U)\simeq V/W$. Could you explain this?